# Error when Facebook sdk Added into android project

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am getting following error while adding Facebook sdk Added into android project

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: see my answer bellow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add bellow line in your build.gradle in android function in defaultConfig

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

then add this dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
```

update your application like bellow

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(base);
    }
```

then mention it into your manifest

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></manifest>
```

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2   
again the same not any change
 please help me bro

Comment: see my upadated answer

Comment: let me knw if you still got any problem

Comment: thanku bro its working fine but buildling app quiet more time

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to try reducing the method size before enable multi-dex.
I think you should check this answer [Error on compile app with Facebook SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36603289/error-on-compile-app-with-facebook-sdk/36603526?noredirect=1#comment60804038_36603526).