# Error on compile app with Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to integrate Facebook in my AOS app and I'm getting this error that I can't figure out how to fix it.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I modified my app | gradle file as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads)

**UPDATE**
Play Services used in this app

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'`

Any ideas?
Thanks,

Comment: do you used play services in gradle? can you post gradle file

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'  remove this line

Comment: use only what service you want!!!

Comment: Sorry @Poovizhirajan.N I added playservices dependencies at question to be more readable.

Comment: no issues use only what ever you want check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue . I solve by by removing unwanted play services

```
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
//Don't use play services directly. use only what ever you want
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
```

Play services having 15+ support libs so you have to use only what you want dont add full play services

Suggested by google service 
[Check Here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)

> Selectively compiling APIs into your executable
>
> In versions of Google Play services prior to 6.5, you had to compile
>   the entire package of APIs into your app. In some cases, doing so made
>   it more difficult to keep the number of methods in your app (including
>   framework APIs, library methods, and your own code) under the 65,536
>   limit.
>
> From version 6.5, you can instead selectively compile Google Play
>   service APIs into your app. For example, to include only the Google
>   Fit and Android Wear APIs, replace the following line in your
>   build.gradle file:
>
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
>
> with these lines:
>
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.4.0'
>
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'
>
> shows a list of the separate APIs that you can include when compiling 
>   your  app, and how to describe them in your build.gradle file. Some APIs > do not have a separate library; include them by including the base
>   library. (This lib is automatically included when you include an API
>   that does have a separate library.)

Comment: Thank you @Poovizhirajan.N this solution worked for me. Also, my previous issued code compiles in Android Studio 2.0. I guess something in new version of gradle fixed the conflicts about support lib or play services libs.

Comment: your welcome always... i faced this by adding same fb api ... my self tried in multidex and so many ways without reading the play services instructions....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when worked with Facebook SDK. This is solution: [How to enable multidexing with the new Android Multidex support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library).

Comment: dont enable muti dex for starting itself.. try to reduce the method size

Comment: Yes, you're right. First of all, you need to try reducing the method size. But after try it, you still get over 64K methods, it's time to enable multi dex.